# Cannot export from any browser

Tags: windows, macos, svg, neo4j, export

I've installed Neo4j, populated the database and produced a graph.  now I want to export it using the built-in functionality but am not having much luck.  here are the browsers I've tried:

1. in OSX Safari (v8.0.6) basically the graph doesn't respond.  I can't move it or double-click on a node or anything.  whatever I try just results in a spinning wheel.
2. in OSX Firefox (v.35.0.1) the graph comes up but attempting an export to PNG results in an error that the file is empty.  same results with exporting an SVG.
3. with Chrome (v43.0.2357.81 64-bit) same thing as with FF, I get empty files.
4. I've also tried it in Windows 7 with Chrome with identical results.

what do I need to do to get a graph out of my database?

*** Update I ***

as per Michael's suggestion, I took a look at the console and see some errors when loading the main page.  these notwithstanding, I can issue queries and get graphs back.  I should also mention that exports to JSON seem to work just fine.

also, there are no messages logged to the console when I attempt an export, the file gets created but it's empty.

[image]

*** Update II ***

I've managed to narrow down the problem.  the Cypher below will create a graph that fails to export as SVG.  taking any line out makes it work.  what's going on here?

```
match (f) optional match (f)-[r]-() delete f, r;
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-1', System: 'UNK' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-2', System: 'Oracle GL' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'X&X', System: 'Classic' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-3', System: 'Classic' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-4', System: 'Sun System' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-5', System: 'Oracle GL' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-6', System: 'Oracle GL' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
merge (DMSrc:DMSys { Org: 'UNK-7', System: 'Direct (No Interface)' }) merge (DMDst:DMSys { Organization: 'UNK-0', System: 'Peoplesoft' }) merge (f:DMFile { Name: 'BAL'}) merge (DMSrc)-[:Provides]->(f)-[:Receives]->(DMDst);
```

Comment: Did you try shift-reload? Which version of Neo4j are you using? Try 2.2.2. Chrome / Webkit has a bug that causes problems with earlier versions.

Comment: I'm running 2.2.0 Neo.  shift-reload? you mean page refresh on the browsers?

Comment: I upgraded to 2.2.2 but still same problem

Comment: Can you check the javascript console of your browser? Is there anything in your graph / nodes that might trip up SVG rendering, e.g. some html content? Can you try with a fresh installation of Neo4j 2.2.2 and just the movie graph? Does SVG work otherwise for you?

Comment: Shift reload is forced reload. You can also go to developer tools, disable cache, reload the page and enable the cache again.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the browser and the javascript console of your browser?

Comment: @MichaelHunger, interestingly a fresh install generates the same errors in Update I, however, an export from the movie database works.  which means it's a data issue.  something with my data is askew

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80440/discussion-between-ekkis-and-michael-hunger).

Comment: @ekkis I was able to reproduce the problem using your code. I think this is definitely some type of bug, and you should report it as an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues) .

Comment: @ErnestoE, thanks for replicating the issue.  I've created a posting on github as you suggested: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is this is a bug.  I've reported it on github here:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4893

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that you want to get an image of the graph, you could take a screenshot of the browser window or a section of it. [See here](https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/keyboard-shortcuts-capture-screen-shot-mac-os-x) for some tips.

Comment: no I can't because the graph doesn't fit in the window