# Utilities for exporting/printing graphs?

Tags: pdf, neo4j

given that the functionality for exporting graphs to SVG or PNG in the Neo4j server page is broken (see [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791364/cannot-export-from-any-browser)), are there any utilities out there that can export a graph from Neo? something that would produce a PDF perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

With not many changes, you could make it work with http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf to format the SVGs in browser to PDF. That set of pages has some d3 samples like this: http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.d3Charts

I took one of the sample charts and rendered to PDF through the Javascript and the remote formatter. The page I selected was here and I took one of those charts:

http://graphgist.neo4j.com/#!/gists/1428842b2170702400451777c2bc813f

The code needs some minor change to ensure that Neo4j puts the svg namespace on the element. The samples on that page do not. But the rendering is near perfect. See the web page on the right and PDF result on the left. I only formatted the SVG and not the whole page (where the silver background exists) and that seems to be the only difference.

[image]

Comment: the problem I have is I can't get Neo to produce an SVG.  the functionality is broken

Comment: OK, well I am not sure where to go with that. I went to that page above and surfed to that sample graph, changed it a bit and opened the developer tools in Chrome and copied the SVG out. I also used the export SVG on that page and it worked. Not sure what doesn't work as I did not implement anything in our side, just used theirs.

Comment: what do you mean by "the functionality is broken", what functionality are you referring to?

Comment: @ErnestoE, what I mean is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791364/cannot-export-from-any-browser

Comment: in a related case I was able to restore functionality in to Chrome by resetting all cache data.